# Jenkins Views: Show Environment Variable

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to display an environment variable as a column in a Jenkins view?

I'm building ruby gems through Jenkins, and I'd like there to be a column which shows the version of the most recently built gem. I can pull that version number from the generated `.gem` file and put it into an environment variable in the build step, but how can I display this in a view?

(See below for an extra column I've added into a view which is how I'd like to see my version number)
[image: Example of Version in a view]

Answer (score 2):

To show custom properties you could use [Extra Columns Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extra+Columns+Plugin). Specifically for your example, you can add version as build description and then re-use it in the extra column plugin configuration